# How to inject Vue3 SFC styles into the DOM in a test environment using Jest and JSDom?

Tags: jestjs, vuejs3, vite, vitest, vue-jest

I want to create a Jest component test for a Vue3 single-file component where I have access to the style tag included in the `.vue` file. Using the JSDom Jest environment and the `vue-jest` transformer which supports styles tags, the component's style should be added to the DOM when mounted with the `mount` function from the `@vue/test-utils` package. But this does not happen.

I have added a minimal example in this [GitHub repository](https://github.com/ursulean/vue-jest-styles-injection/tree/main) for anyone who wants to reproduce this issue with my setup. When running `npm test` on the above repository, the following output is produced, showing that the style tag is not present in the head of the document.

```
> vue-jest-styles-injection@0.0.0 test
> jest

 FAIL  src/components/HelloWorld.test.ts
  HelloWorld.vue
    ✕ takes a screenshot with hello world (12 ms)

  ● HelloWorld.vue › takes a screenshot with hello world

    expect(received).toContain(expected) // indexOf

    Expected substring: "style"
    Received string:    "<html><head></head><body><div data-v-app=\"\"><h1>Hello, world!</h1><div class=\"card\"><button type=\"button\">count is 0</button><p> Edit <code>components/HelloWorld.vue</code> to test HMR </p></div><p> Check out <a href=\"https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html#local\" target=\"_blank\">create-vue</a>, the official Vue + Vite starter </p><p> Install <a href=\"https://github.com/vuejs/language-tools\" target=\"_blank\">Volar</a> in your IDE for a better DX </p><p class=\"read-the-docs\">Click on the Vite and Vue logos to learn more</p></div></body></html>"

       6 |   it('takes a screenshot with hello world', async () => {
       7 |     mount(HelloWorld, { props: { msg: "Hello, world!" }, attachTo: document.body });
    >  8 |     expect(document.documentElement.outerHTML).toContain("style")
         |                                                ^
       9 |   });
      10 | });

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/HelloWorld.test.ts:8:48)
```

I tried using the [Vitest](https://vitest.dev/) testing framework instead of Jest, and I was able to mount the component and its styles to the DOM as intended. I have also included this working example on a [branch](https://github.com/ursulean/vue-jest-styles-injection/tree/vitest) in my repository.

While Vitest looks great, the real repository I want to integrate these tests into is already using Jest and has quite a complex setup which I expect will be difficult to migrate to Vitest. So I want to get this working using Jest.

Since the Vitest setup works, I suspect the issue is with my Jest configuration. I tried adding the following `vue-jest` options to my `jest.config.ts` file, but there was no difference when running the test.

```
  globals: {
    "vue-jest": {
      "hideStyleWarn": true,
      "experimentalCSSCompile": true
    }
  }
```

I also looked inside of the `@vue/vue-jest` and `@vue/compiler-sfc` packages, but was unable to find a solution.